# Dynamically set role="status" with vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm looking for a way to set the `role="status"` attribute using vue.

Something like
`:role="{'status': isStatus}"`

```
<span class="result-total" role="status">
  <span class="result-number">{{ resultNumber }}</span>
  <label>Results found</label>
</span>
```

Comment: Can you please share some working example of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:role="{'status': isStatus}"` is special syntax usable only for `style` and `class` bindings. For anything else you need to use standard JS bindings.

Computed property is best and most performant solution:

```js
computed: {
  role() { return isStatus ? 'status' : '' }
}
```

```html
<span class="result-total" :role="role">
  <span class="result-number">{{ resultNumber }}</span>
  <label>Results found</label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set strings based on a boolean you can do something like this:

```
:role="isStatus ? 'status' : ''"
```

Change `''` to whatever default role you want.

See JavaScript documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator